# How to cache images ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, caching

I currently have an array with lots of image URLs called `images` They are being put into my table like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row=%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"images[indexPath.row]=%@", [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    NSString *stringy = @"http://www.tragicclothing.co.uk/";
    NSString *link = [stringy stringByAppendingString: images[indexPath.row]];
    NSString* encodedString = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString]];
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.opaque = NO;
    cell.backgroundView = nil;

    return cell;
}
```

But this is causing a lot of lag when scrolling. How could I cache the data? to prevent this lag? I have seen [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) but I don't quite know how to use it! It seems very complicated.

Should I be using

```
SDImageCache *imageCache = [[SDImageCache alloc] initWithNamespace:@"myNamespace"];
[imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:myCacheKey done:^(UIImage *image)
{
    // image is not nil if image was found
}];
```

Comment: you are calling SDWebImage as complicated? What else you want? Just call method [myImage setImage....

Comment: [myImage setImage.... ?

Comment: The lag is not caused simply by scrolling. You're downloading the image synchronously, that's your problem!

Comment: @Cyrille How would I download it all at once. I want to make a sort of infinity scroll type thing...

Comment: you dont need to download all image at once, let the get downloaded asysnchronously.

Comment: You are doing synchronous networking on the main thread. That is not good, and that is the likely source of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing can be simple then [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

it prodide the following solution

An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to the Cocoa Touch framework

An asynchronous image downloader

An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

NSString* encodedString = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row=%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"images[indexPath.row + 7]=%@", [images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 7]);


    NSString *stringy = @"http://www.tragicclothing.co.uk/";
    NSString *link = [stringy stringByAppendingString: images[indexPath.row + 7]];
    NSString* encodedString = [link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Comp 2_00000.png"]];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.opaque = NO;
    cell.backgroundView = nil;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: +1 Obviously, with a `#import` of the `UIImageView` category.

Comment: Thanks rob! I will add the import when i get a chance( on my phone now :-s)